# Dynamic lambda using an expression builder for select

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I am trying to write a dynamic select statement. I have the following:

```
public class MainList
{
    public string Prop1{ get; set; }
    public string Prop2{ get; set; }
    public string Prop3{ get; set; }       
}

public class SearchObject
{
    public string Prop1{ get; set; }
}
```

I want build the expression like the following

```
var newList = MainList.Select(n => new SearchObject { Prop1 = n.Prop1});
```

The code I am using creates a list based on MainList. I then create the select expression by passing the SearchObject type and the parameters I want to populate, for now. It runs until the second to last line.

```
public void Start()
{
    List<MainList> newList = new List<MainList>(); //This has a ton list objects
    var result = newList.Select(CreateSelect<SearchObject>("Prop1"));
}

public static Func<MainList, T> CreateSelect<T>(string fields)
{
    var par = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "n");

    var newInstance= Expression.New(typeof(T));

    var bindings = fields.Split(',').Select(o => o.Trim())
        .Select(n => {

            var p = typeof(T).GetProperty(n);

            var original = Expression.Property(par, p);

            return Expression.Bind(p, original);
        }
    );

    var newT= Expression.MemberInit(newInstance, bindings);

    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<MainList, T>>(newT, par); //ERROR HAPPENS HERE
    return lambda.Compile();
}
```

The error I get is:

Additional information: ParameterExpression of type 'WebApplication.SearchObject' cannot be used for delegate parameter of type 'WebApplication.MainList'

I am unsure on the meaning of the error and also how to resolve the issue.

Comment: I'm assuming you're trying to create an reporting application or something of some sort.  You could use [DynamicLinq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic/), but you're better off either creating mapping, or using oData

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first issue is, as already mentioned by Jeroen van Langen, the type of the parameter must be `MainList`.

The second issue is the usage of the [`Expression.Bind`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298030(v=vs.110).aspx). Since the source and target are different types, you cannot use one and the same `PropertyInfo`. The first argument must be a `PropertyInfo` of the target type `T`, while the second - expression coming from the source type `MainList` (in your case, `Expression.Property` on the parameter with the specified property name).

The correct implementation is something like this:

```
public static Func<MainList, T> CreateSelect<T>(string fields)
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(MainList), "n");
    var bindings = fields.Split(',')
        .Select(name => name.Trim())
        .Select(name => Expression.Bind(
            typeof(T).GetProperty(name),
            Expression.Property(parameter, name)
        ));
    var newT = Expression.MemberInit(Expression.New(typeof(T)), bindings);
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<MainList, T>>(newT, parameter);
    return lambda.Compile();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The exception *`ParameterExpression of type 'WebApplication.SearchObject' cannot be used for delegate parameter of type 'WebApplication.MainList'`* explained:

Meaning: There is a mismatch between the `ParameterExpression` type *`typeof(T)`* and the Expression.Lambda `Func<MainList, T>` -->   *`MainList`*

Your:

```
var par = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "n");
```

should be:

```
var par = Expression.Parameter(typeof(MainList), "n");
```

Comment: When I change the code like that it fails at the following line: 'var original = Expression.Property(par, p);' with the error Property 'System.String Prop1' is not defined for type 'WebApplication.MainList'

Comment: `var p = typeof(T).GetProperty(n);` type (t) should be MainList also.

Comment: It then fails at line: var newT= Expression.MemberInit(newInstance, bindings); with the error 'Prop1' is not a member of type 'WebApplication.SearchObject'

Comment: You might consider what you are doing. We're close by rewriting the whole thing. I personally never used the 'bind' expression.